# Microsoft teams delete an adaptive card using activity id

Tags: node.js, botframework, microsoft-teams

I am using nodejs and able to show an adaptive card with action as below

```
{
                "type": "Action.Submit",
                "title": "Hide details",
                "data": { "action" : "hideDetails", "activity_id": context.activity.id}
            }

....
await context.sendActivity(myCard);
```

so basically on the button, i am passing the activity id of the current context.

now on the hideDetails the code looks like below

```
 async hideDetails(context:any, activityId:any){
        await context.deleteActivity(activityId)
}
```

However, I am getting below error

```
Invalid activity ID f:ef8e3a07-59fe-2eb9-a717-e89c0ca664ba
    at new RestError (/workspace/node_modules/@azure/ms-rest-js/dist/msRest.node.js:1397:28)
```

what's wrong here?

Comment: Hi @Moblize IT, Could you please check the activity Id is a valid one and please have a try with [this sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/492bbc16c09998efcf935055b2378822373464f0/samples/javascript_nodejs/57.teams-conversation-bot/bots/teamsConversationBot.js#L201).

Comment: Thank you so much! it was the replyToId that i needed

Comment: Hi @Moblize IT, Could you please confirm whether the issue is resolved?

Comment: yes it did. thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copying the answer from comments for better visibility.

[ReplyToId](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.schema.activity.replytoid?view=botbuilder-dotnet-stable) of the Activity Property can be used to Update or delete the message posted to the bot and this is illustrated in Teams Conversation Bot code [sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/492bbc16c09998efcf935055b2378822373464f0/samples/javascript_nodejs/57.teams-conversation-bot).

Comment: I'm running the sample locally and getting a similar error `'activityId' cannot be null`.

Comment: I solved my issue. It looks like if the bot is being tested through the Bot Framework Emulator, the `activityId` will be null. I used [ngrok to test the bot locally in Microsoft Teams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/authentication/add-authentication?tabs=dotnet%2Cdotnet-sample#testing-the-bot-locally-in-teams) and then `activityId` had a value. So, the bot just has to run in Teams.